# Как добавить существующий файл в проект на Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, c++

Использую среду разработки Eclipse для C++. Проект находится в одной папке, а файлы в другой. Почему-то не получается добавить существующие файлы в проект? Как это сделать?

Существуют C++ и H-файлы в одной директории. В другой директории создаю проект. Файлы из первой директории должны быть частью нового проекта. Пытаюсь добавить в Eclipse эти файлы в новый проект... не получается... Возможно ли это?

Comment: @sitev_ru, вы хотите, чтобы среда их копировала или просто работала с ними? Импортируете в новый проект или в существующий?

Comment: просто работала с ними...